# Allowing slash in slug/permalinks

Tags: permalinks, advanced-custom-fields, slug

I'm trying to create slugs on WordPress posts based on input from some Advanced Custom Fields and the post title.

The code below creates the slug based on the data in the fields, but only the two slashes (between month and year) are stripped out so the slug looks like this: 201710postname-venue instead of 2017/10/postname-venue

```
// Auto-create post slug with eventyear, post title and venue
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

// Only trigger on posts
if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) {

// Bail if no ACF
if( empty($_POST['acf']) ) {
   return;
}

// Retrieve data to create slug
$myslug = date_i18n('Y', strtotime( get_field('date-concert', $post->ID, false) )) ."/". date_i18n('m', strtotime( get_field('date-concert', $post->ID, false) )) ."/". get_the_title($post) .'-'. get_field('venue', $post->ID, false);
$post   = array(
    'ID'            => $post_id,
    'post_name'     => $myslug
);

wp_update_post($post);

}
}

// Run before saving post
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 1);
```

Is is possible to create a permalink structure, like the default /%year%/%month%/%postname%/ – but then with year and month input from an advanced custom field?

Comment: You should be able to do that with WP's [rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). Might be easier to use a plugin like Custom Permalinks.

Comment: Hello Janh, thank you. I will look in to the rewrite rules. I would prefer not to use any plug-in, but have this generated automatically so permalinks are always the same structure, no matter which users creates the post.

Comment: Custom Permalinks just uses a postmeta field "custom_permalink", that you can totally set yourself during `save_post`, but knowing your way around rewrite rules will definitely benefit you in the future.

Comment: I have never really used a rewrite rule for such a function, so I hope I can find a solution. :')

Comment: i'm guessing `/` is not accepted, you can just use `-` instead, or use rewrite rules as suggested